# How do you make Speech to Text work in Windows (Phone) 8.1 Universal App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, text-to-speech, win-universal-app

I'm trying to write code to read aloud an incoming Toast (this was trivial in WP8.1)
I have this so far

- Using MediaElement doesn't seem to work (code runs but no audio) either on the phone or in the
  emulator
- Using BackgroundMediaPlayer works in the emulator but not on the phone

I've tried both from the UI thread (MediaElement only works on the UI thread) and BackgroundMediaPlayer from the thread that handles the incoming toast

```
var mediaElement = new MediaElement();
using (var tts = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    using (var ttsStream = await tts.SynthesizeSsmlToStreamAsync(ssml))
    {
        //BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetStreamSource(ttsStream);
        mediaElement.SetSource(ttsStream, ttsStream.ContentType);
        mediaElement.Play();
    }
}
```

I'm obviously missing something simple here but I'm out of ideas how to make this work.
The SSML is correct, I think it's probably something to do with scoping and threads

Comment: Amazingly (I need to do a bit more testing) I think it's the using around the ttsStream. I think this might be the first time I've been bitten by cleaning up after myself

Comment: Yep, you're killing the stream before it has a chance to actually play. I did the same thing when I first got into it. Also, you may want to consider explicitly setting the stream position to 0 before passing it to mediaElement. I seem to remember that every now again (intermittently and inconsistently) it would be at some other position before Play() was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
     var voice = SpeechSynthesizer.DefaultVoice;
     var newuserText = TheMessage
     var stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(newuserText);
     var mediaElement = new MediaElement();
     mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
     mediaElement.Play();
```