# Text To Speech universal app doesn't work

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, text-to-speech, win-universal-app, speech, winrt-async

This code doesn't work in windows universal app 10

```
        var mediaPronunciation = new MediaElement();

        using (var speech = new SpeechSynthesizer())
        {
            speech.Voice = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices
                .First(i => i.Gender == VoiceGender.Male);

            var voiceStream = await speech.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("fast");

            mediaPronunciation.SetSource(voiceStream, voiceStream.ContentType);
            mediaPronunciation.Play();
        }
```

I've got this error

> {"The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)":null}

I find this topic and he has same problem  
[How do you make Speech to Text work in Windows (Phone) 8.1 Universal App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880379/how-do-you-make-speech-to-text-work-in-windows-phone-8-1-universal-app)

please help how can I fix this problem?

[image: This image show Marker is null]

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var speech= new SpeechSynthesizer();
speech.Voice = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices
            .First(i => i.Gender == VoiceGender.Male);
SpeechSynthesisStream sss =await speech.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("fast");
mediaPronunciation.SetSource(sss, sss.ContentType);
mediaPronunciation.Play();
```

Try this...

Comment: Thanks dude, it doesn't work i think problem is this code speech.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("fast"), u know why? Because i check the Marker property and it was null and i think it's the main cause, some guys said voice doesn't install in your os but i'm sure it isn't problem

Comment: check out microphone in your Package.appxmanifest --> Microphone

Comment: it wasn't checked but I checked and it doesn't work still.

Comment: I use this sample --> https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis                                      and I this handle error with this message ->Media player components unavailable

Comment: it's totally about mediaElement I run app in Mobile Emulator and it works great but in windows desktop device it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fix this,
every one have to download this file for player :
[Download and install media pack for N SKU of Windows 10 introduced](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3010081) 
 , Now you can enjoy use Text To Speech

thanks a lot Mr. Fred -> [My question in MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/74b782ae-1a41-4207-8fb7-d4cfacf6a7c5/uwp-text-to-speech-universal-app-doesnt-work#3b60c0e6-9395-4bc9-91c1-046bc987d8ab)